# Run docker gitlab with apache on ubuntu

Tags: docker, apache, gitlab, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to start gitlab running on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have already an apache server running.

```
sudo docker run --detach \
--hostname hostname.de \
--publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

when i try to run that docker image i get the following error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use.
```

I run already a few websites on my apache webserver so i already use port 80 and 443.
How can I run that docker gitlab image beside my apache server?

Comment: Use a proxy server, only one app can listen on a port, which would be your proxy server. I like nginx.

Comment: Any more information on how to setup this?

Comment: In your GitLab config, listen on non-standard ports (for example 8080 for http and 8443 for https), then [use nginx as a reverse proxy that forwards to those ports](https://serverfault.com/a/171680/621084).